# Handling pandas indices in sklearn pipeline with custom transformers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am transforming my code base over to using Pipelines, because they are an excellent tool. However, I have the following requirements:

0. The input to `predict`-type methods should be a pandas dataframe.
1. The input to `predict` or `score_samples` should be the entire dataframe.
2. All preprocessing should be handled by the pipeline.
3. I need to drop NaN rows, but the result must have the same index as the original dataframe.
4. I need to postprocess the results to handle certain missing values a specific way.

It seems postprocessing using pipelines is difficult without writing a wrapper of some sort (see : [How to define a pipeline in python with three steps: preprocessing, predicting and postprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373800/how-to-define-a-pipeline-in-python-with-three-steps-preprocessing-predicting-a)), and I'm okay with that. It does add complexity to accessing methods/attributes on the pipeline and its steps however, so I don't want to take that approach to solve the problem in the following paragraph.

The tricky part (to me) is handling the dropped rows and maintaining the index. If I drop rows during `pipeline.predict`, then the input shape `df.shape` does not match the output shape `ndarray.shape`. I don't want the end user to have to manage the index transformations.

A simple toy problem to show what I've come up with so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from typing import List, Union, Callable

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.choice([np.nan, np.inf, 1, 2], p=[0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2], size=[10, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"column_1": data[:, 0], "column_2": data[:, 1]},
    index=pd.date_range("2023-01-01", "2023-01-01 00:09:00", freq="1T"),
)

class DropInvalidRows(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.removed_indices = None
        self.inf_indices = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, df, y=None):
        self.inf_indices = df.index[
            (df.abs()==np.inf).any(axis=1)
        ]
        self.removed_indices = df.index[
            df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).isna().any(axis=1)
        ]
        return df.drop(self.removed_indices)
def use_pipeline_on_dataframe(
    df: pd.DataFrame, pipeline: Pipeline, method="predict"
):
    """Make predictions with a Pipeline, and reindex to ``df``.

    An sklearn pipeline will convert the predictions to a numpy array. Some
    pipeline steps will also drop rows from the DataFrame. So when we call
    ``predictions = Pipeline.predict(df)``, predictions will not have an index,
    and it will not necessarily have the same length as ``df``. Any custom
    transformer that drops rows should implement a ``removed_indices``
    attribute, which allows us to reconstruct the original indices.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : DataFrame
        Test data.
    pipeline : Pipeline
        An sklearn pipeline.
    method : str
        A method from an sklearn pipeline. E.g., ``pipeline.predict`` or
        ``pipeline.score_samples``. The referenced method should take one 
        argument, the DataFrame to make computations on.

    Returns
    -------
    DataFrame
        Predictions from ``pipeline`` with the original index of ``df``.
    """
    function = getattr(pipeline, method, None)
    if function is None:
        raise ValueError(
            "{method} is not a method on the Pipeline instance provided"
        )
    df_subset = df.copy()
    predictions = function(df)
    for step_name, step in pipeline.steps:
        removed_indices = getattr(step, "removed_indices", None)
        if removed_indices is not None:
            df_subset = df_subset.drop(removed_indices, errors="ignore")
    return pd.Series(predictions, index=df_subset.index).reindex(df.index)

pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
    ("rem-rows", DropInvalidRows()),
    ("predictor", IsolationForest()) # NaN rows must be removed
]).fit(df.copy())
result_pipeline = pipe.score_samples(df)
result_func = use_pipeline_on_dataframe(df, pipe, method="score_samples")
print("Raw pipeline usage")
display(result_pipeline) # array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
print("Result from `use_pipeline_on_dataframe`")
display(result_func)
print("Desired result")
result_func.loc[pipe["rem-rows"].inf_indices] = np.inf
display(result_func)
```

Any custom transformers I write that drop rows must implement the same interface. It's not a huge problem, but it seems pretty clunky given how common I assume this must be. It forces the user to remember to call the `use_pipeline_on_dataframe` method, they need to know how to implement the postprocessing, and to access the indices from a particular part of the pipeline. Chaining postprocessing together may get tricky and hard to scale with larger pipelines.

Is there a native way to handle these types of situations with Pipelines?